# Using string as an ID of graphical element in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to use a string as an ID of ImageView in Android project.
This code does not work form me:

```
    for(int l=1; l<=9; l++){
        String NineElements = "imageView" + l;
        ImageView oneOfNineElements = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.NineElements);
        oneOfNineElements.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage));
    }
```

Comment: **findViewById** works only with `int` variables

Answer (score 0):

id s in Android are generated in build process if you want to use them in loop you can save them in array and loop over them

```
int[] images = {R.id.image1,R.id.image2,....
```

then

```
for(int l=1; l<=9; l++){

    ImageView oneOfNineElements = (ImageView)findViewById(images[l]);
    oneOfNineElements.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It should work

```
for(int l = 1; l <= 9; l++)
    {
        String elementID = "imageView" + l;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(elementID, "id", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        ImageView oneOfNineElements = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
        oneOfNineElements.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage));
    }
```